# multiple Constructors and if Statement

Tags: java, constructor-chaining

I want to, within my abstract `class`, define two constructors.

When create a new instance of the `class`, i want the toString to return something different depending on what was called:

The FireEngine `Class`

```
public class FireEngine extends EmergencyVehicle {  

    private String colour;

    public FireEngine(String colour) {
        super (colour);

    }
    public FireEngine() {
        this("red");

    }

    public String toString () {
        if (colour == "red") {
            return "red";
    }   else
        return "no";
    }
}
```

The `EmergencyVehicle` class:

```
public abstract class  EmergencyVehicle extends RoadVehicle {

    public boolean codeBlue = false;

    public EmergencyVehicle(String colour){
        super(colour);
    }

    public boolean isEmergency () {
        if (codeBlue == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setEmergency(boolean newEmergency) {
        codeBlue = newEmergency;
    }

}
```

This is a homework exercise so I don't want the answer per se, but does the above code make sense?

For example, if I add a new EmergencyVehicle, I want an if statement depending on what colour the vehicle I add is.

Comment: where is your EmergencyVehicle class ? Post it here

Comment: Well, not really makes sense, although your intention was probably clear... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Instead of String maybe you might want to use a predefined Color type? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Comment: Your `isEmergency` method could be hugely simplified to `return codeBlue;`

Comment: What is `RoadVehicle(String colour)` doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st Remark**

Don't call

```
this("red");
```

in the default constructor, do

```
colour = "red";
```

unless the <strike>`EmergencyVehicle(String colour)`</strike> `RoadVehicle(String colour)` constructor is doing something else.

**2nd Remark**

Don't compare using

```
if (colour == "red")
```

use

```
if ("red".equals(colour))
```

**3rd Remark**

The method

```
public String toString()
```

is supposed to return a string representation of the instance. You implementation only returns `red` or `no` which is not very informative. Use something like

```
return("FireEngine(colour=" + colour + ")");
```

Comment: What is wrong with `this("red")`? Maybe the super call properly does `colour = "red"`

Comment: @cricket_007 Probably not. Note `private String colour;`.

Comment: But then there would be no need for the `private String colour;`

Comment: @Grunzwanzling 'then': in which case? I doubt that the OP knows about how to structure a class hierachy.

Comment: Right. Your answer is fine, just unclear what the parent class is doing

Comment: I am sorry. It was meant as an answer to @cricket_007. I meant the same thing as you.

Comment: @Grunzwanzling Thanks for the help! I removed the `Private String Colour` and it worked. I am new to coding, so could you explain what was causing the code not to work properly with setting the String Colour as private